# How do I find config.xml in cordova?

Tags: cordova

I have created the initial cordova app as shown in the Apache cordova documentation and it runs smoothly. Now I want to modify the app by adding html as well as css and javascript features. However, I cannot get access to the config.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the config/xml file in the app folder in the C:drive.